# Error when migrating database to Heroku (NameError: Uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have been running my app locally on my machine and thought I was ready to push it to Heroku. (I have SQL on development/test but PG on production as recommended.) The issue I have is that in the past, I have multiple migrations that have created a Devise model called *companies*, added the attribute manually *company_id* to my Devise model *users*, renamed *companies* to *accounts*, and renamed *company_id* to *account_id*. When doing all of these migrations back then, my schema nicely reflected what was going on. However now that I am running all these migrations at once for Heroku, things are getting a bit hairy.

### Specific Errors:

#### 1)

Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.4418
Migrating to AddCompanyIdToUsers (20140521170926)
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant AddCompanyIdToUsers

#### 2)

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError:
Multiple migrations have the name AddAccountIdToUsers

### Specific Solutions

Based on answers to other SO questions, I have tried different things: I have tried destroying the said migrations since they are no longer relevant. I have tried rolling back the migration to the ones prior, deleting the problem migration file, and migrating the database again. I have also tried renaming the migration file and/or class name within migration and/or model names within migration. Everything to no avail.

### Relevant Migrations

20140521170926_add_company_id_to_users.rb

```
class AddCompanyIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :account_id, :integer
  end
end
```

20140527013603_rename_companies_to_accounts.rb

```
class RenameCompaniesToAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :companies, :accounts
  end
end
```

20140610013557_remove_account_id_from_users.rb

```
class RemoveAccountIdFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :users, :account_id, :integer
  end
end
```

20140614021611_add_account_id_to_users.rb

```
class AddAccountIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :account_id, :integer
  end
end
```

As you can see, I got a bit indecisive about some of my decisions but thought performing migrations like above would be cleaner but it doesn't seem to be working as smoothly as I liked. I can update with my schema if needed. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Everyone changes their mind with database structure, it's no biggie

I would do this if I were you:

> 1. Go through all your `migrations` (there can't be *that* many?)
> 2. For each migration, I would identify what has changed, and amend the original `create` migration to reflect your changes
> 3. For the migrations you override, I would remove all the contents inside the `def change` method (so the migration is blank)
> 4. `git add .` all these ammended migrations & deploy to `heroku`
> 5. Run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

This should fix your errors, although it may take some time to amend all your original migrations!

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback. I have commented out the contents of every migration above and updated the create users migration with account_id. In spite of doing all this, I am still getting the same error for the 20140521170926 migration above (uninitialized constant). Just curious also if there's a camel case issue here.